# Java Converting String(day/month/year) format to Date

Tags: java, string, date

I am trying to conver the string to a date

```
String date = "12/31/2012";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        try {
            Date parse = sdf.parse(date);
            System.out.println(parse);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {     
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it appears to me that it is having an `Exception`. of `ParseExpception`. why is that? I want to generate a date for `12/31/2012`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Date String - `12/31/2012`

It matches with - `MM/dd/yyyy`

- d - Day of the month
- M - Month in year
- y - Year

...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

format for month is `MM` not `mm` and also your should should delimit with `-` and not `/` as your formatter delimiter is `/` and your format should match your date atring.

```
date 12-31-2012
fmt  MM-dd-yyyy


String date = "12-31-2012";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

[If You could use Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
String dateStr = "11/15/2013";
Date date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseDateTime(dateStr).toDate();
```